# Backup and recover user roles oracle

Tags: oracle, backup, roles, restore, settings

Is it possible to backup user roles (not the whole DB) with a script or is there some backup function in oracle 11 ?
I want to backup the users and restore them later by script, this should be used as a backup against mis configurations.

DBA_USERS
DBA_ROLES
DBA_ROLE_PRIVS
ROLE_TAB_PRIVS
SESSION_PRIVS
SESSION_ROLES
TABLE_PRIVILEGES

Currently, i can query or create views of the tables that store most of the user settings. But creating roles and granting right on tables from that source involves a lot of text transformation.
view > store to file > concat convert them to create/grant > execute script on commandline

Is there another way to export AND import user rights and roles and the way they are assigned to tables ? Or can i simply backup and restore the tables mentioned in this question without braking the DB?

Comment: This may give you some pointers in the right direction:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/826744?start=0

Answer (score 1):

You can use datapump to backup them:

```
expdp cyrille/*******@//localhost:1521/orclpdb \
dumpfile=exp_USER_GRANTS.dmp \
logfile=exp_USER_GRANTS.log \
directory=MY_DIRECTORY \
INCLUDE=GRANT \
INCLUDE=OBJECT_GRANT \
INCLUDE=SYSTEM_GRANT \
INCLUDE=ROLE_GRANT \
INCLUDE=USER \
full=y

Export: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Sep 27 11:35:35 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Starting "*****"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01":  cyrille/********@//localhost:1521/orclpdb dumpfile=exp_USER_GRANTS.dmp logfile=exp_USER_GRANTS.log directory=MY_DIRECTORY INCLUDE=GRANT INCLUDE=OBJECT_GRANT INCLUDE=SYSTEM_GRANT INCLUDE=ROLE_GRANT INCLUDE=USER full=y
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYS_USER/USER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/USER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/GRANT/SYSTEM_GRANT/PROC_SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/GRANT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/SEQUENCE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/GRANT/PROCOBJ_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/FUNCTION/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCEDURE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/JAVA_CLASS/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/JAVA_RESOURCE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/OPERATOR/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/INDEXTYPE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Master table "CYRILLE"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for CYRILLE.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01 is:
  /u01/exp_USER_GRANTS.dmp
```

From that dump you can also generate a script using the sqlfile parameter:

```
impdp cyrille/******@//localhost:1521/orclpdb  dumpfile=exp_USER_GRANTS.dmp  logfile=imp_USER_GRANTS.log  directory=MY_DIRECTORY sqlfile=my_script.sql
```

this will generate a sql file with the scripts.